# Get milliseconds for custom date in custom timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have a date server api that works in Europe/Moscow timezone. The selected date must be sent from the client as a timestamp for the Europe/Moscow timezone.

A client from Canada choosing a date in the calendar, say November 8, 2011 has to send the timestamp in the Europe/Moscow timezone.

I can solve this problem through moment.js, but unfortunately, for certain reasons I can't use third-party libraries in the project.

Basically I need a function that does the same thing as the moment.tz method:

moment.tz('2021-11-08T00:00:00', 'Europe/Moscow');

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Intl.DateTimeFormat* with suitable options to get a timestamp for any IANA location. The *formatToParts* method gets the required values, then it's just a matter of formatting them. E.g.

```js
function toLocTimestamp(loc, date = new Date()) {
  let {year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZoneName} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: loc,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
  }).formatToParts().reduce((parts, part) => {
    parts[part.type] = part.value;
    return parts;
  }, Object.create(null));
  
  // Check if timezone not offset and fix
  if (!/\d/.test(timeZoneName)) {
    timeZoneName = date.toLocaleString('fr',{
      hour: 'numeric',
      timeZone: loc,
      timeZoneName: 'short'
    }).match(/\S+$/)[0];
  }
  // Change timeZoneName to offset
  let sign = timeZoneName.substring(3,4);
  let offset = timeZoneName.substring(4);
  let [offH, offM] = offset.split(':');
  // Return timestamp
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}${sign}${offH.padStart(2,'0')}:${offM || '00'}`;
}

// E.g.
['Europe/Moscow', 'Asia/Kolkata','Australia/Lord_Howe',
 'America/St_Johns'].forEach(
  loc => console.log(`${loc.padEnd(20,' ')}: ${toLocTimestamp(loc)}`)
 );
```

The *timeZoneName* fix is required as depending on the language passed to *dateTimeFormat* and host system language, the offset might be GMT±H[:mm], UTC±H[:mm] or an abbreviation like "ChST" or "CET". If en returns an abbreviation, fr shouldn't.

This will observe DST for various locations. If a fixed offset is required, just adjust the UTC time by the offset, use *toISOString* to get the timestamp and remove the trailing Z.